# Update UIViewRepresentable size from UIKit in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm embedding a view controller with variable-height `UITextView` inside a parent SwiftUI VStack and the view controller sizes it's frame to the whole screen between `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. The `UITextView` expands only to the size of the text inside itself and centers itself inside the parent view.

I'm trying to add this view controller in a VStack and have it behave externally like other SwiftUI components do - sized exactly to the content it contains - but it wants to be sized to the whole screen minus the other VStack elements.

I can get the correct size of the `UITextView` in `didLayoutSubviews` and pass it upwards to SwiftUI where it can be set properly - but where do I do that?

In the example screenshot below, the orange is the embedded `UIView` background, the green is the `UITextView` and the VStack looks like this:

```
    VStack {
        HighligherVC()
        Text("Tap and drag to highlight")
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .font(.caption)
    }
```

[image: example of the parent uiview expanding to be too high]

Comment: I had a similiar question and generalized the question with a runnable example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832221/passing-uikit-uiview-size-to-swiftui-in-uiviewrepresentable

Answer (score 6):

Without being able to see more of your code, it's slightly difficult to say what the best solution would be, but based purely on this part of your question...

> I can get the correct size of the UITextView in didLayoutSubviews and pass it upwards to SwiftUI where it can be set properly - but where do I do that?

I would suggest that you pass a binding property to your view controller that can be set to the calculated text view height, meaning that the view that contains your `VStack` would have a `@State` property like this:

```swift
@State private var textViewHeight: CGFloat = 0
```

You would then declare a `@Binding` property on your `HighlighterVC` and add an initializer like this:

```swift
@Binding var textViewHeight: CGFloat

init(textViewHeight: Binding<CGFloat>) {
    self._textViewHeight = textViewHeight
}
```

And then you would set `textViewHeight` to the calculated height in your `didLayoutSubviews` and add a `.frame` modifier to your `HighlighterVC` like this:

```swift
VStack {
    HighlighterVC(textViewHeight: self.$textViewHeight)
        .frame(height: self.textViewHeight)
    Text("Tap and drag to highlight")
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .font(.caption)
}
```

Like I said at the beginning of my answer, this solution (that I believe would work, but since I can't test it, I'm not 100% certain) is based on your thoughts about what it is that you need. Without seeing more code, it's impossible for me to say if this is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Add fixedSize may solve this.
`.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)`

Comment: This is much easier and should be selected as the correct answer.