# UIViewRepresentable automatic size - Passing UIKit UIView size to SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

Assume you have a UIKit view that wants to decide about its own size (via intrinsicContentSize or layout constraints, the size might change). For example:

```swift
/// Some UIKit view that wants to have a specific size
class YellowBoxUIKitView : UIView {

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) is not supported")
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }

}
```

How can you wrap this as a SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable and make it pass on the UIView size to SwiftUI automatically?

```swift
struct YellowBoxView : UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> YellowBoxUIKitView {
        // TODO: How do you pass the size from UIKit up to SwiftUI?
        YellowBoxUIKitView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: YellowBoxUIKitView, context: Context) {
    }

}
```

SwiftUI does not respect the size of the UIView and just give it maximum possible width/height.

Runnable example: [SizedUIViewRepresentableView](https://github.com/ralfebert/SwiftUIPlayground/blob/master/SwiftUIPlayground/Views/SizedUIViewRepresentableView.swift)

There is a similiar question asked for a UITextView here: [Update UIViewRepresentable size from UIKit in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237580/update-uiviewrepresentable-size-from-uikit-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The solution is to set explicitly compression/hugging priority for represented `UIView`

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct YellowBoxView : UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> YellowBoxUIKitView {
        let view = YellowBoxUIKitView()

        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal) // << here !!
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)

        // the same for compression if needed

        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: YellowBoxUIKitView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note, looks like this strategy doesn't work for UIStackViews. Seems like stacks always take all the area available to them.

Comment: Replacing the two `setContentHuggingPriority ` with `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in the `makeUIView` worked for me.

Comment: For stack views we solved using the UIKit view's intrinsicContentSize: stackView.layoutIfNeeded(); return CGSize(width: stackView.frame.size.width, height: stackView.frame.size. height)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if using makeUIViewController. Tried uiViewController.view.setContentCompressionResistance and it had no effect.