# Autoresize UILabel within View

Tags: uikit, swiftui

Looking for a solution for the following:

```
struct AttributedParagraph: View {

    private let attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString

    init (_ text: String) {
        self.attributedText = text.attributed // tiny markdown parser
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        ...
        attributedText.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, ...)
        attributedText.addAttribute(.font, ...)
    }

    var body: some View {
        // Wrap it so padding for example works
        Group {
            AttributedText(attributedText: self.attributedText)
        }
    }
}

struct AttributedText: UIViewRepresentable {

    var attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        return UILabel()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AttributedText>) {
        uiView.attributedText = self.attributedText
        uiView.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        uiView.numberOfLines = 0
        uiView.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

How do I make `AttributedParagraph` to behave like `Text` in SwiftUI? At the moment the `UILabel` ignores all constraints passed from container and produces one long line. Ideally I'd like `UILable` to automatically break the lines whilst respecting the width provided by `AttributedParagraph`, and adjust its height to fit the content.

Comment: See solution in [Passing UIKit UIView size to SwiftUI in UIViewRepresentable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832221/passing-uikit-uiview-size-to-swiftui-in-uiviewrepresentable)

Comment: Thank you! This one worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237580/update-uiviewrepresentable-size-from-uikit-in-swiftui

Comment: It seems hugging alone clashed with ScrollView calculations and labels got truncated.